# flot bar chart data label left offset

Tags: jquery, charts, alignment, flot, label

I am reading data from an xml object into an array, six items in total. The chart renders fine, all colours and height of each vertical bar is ok. When I try to add data labels to each vertical bar, the labels all appear at the right height from the top of the relevant bars, but they are all aligned to the left axis.

[image]

The left property of o.left in the code below always returns a NaN value.

```
$.each(plot.getData()[0].data, function(i, el){

            var o = plot.pointOffset({x: el[0], y: el[1]});

            $('<div class="data-point-label">' + el[1] + '</div>').css( {
                position: 'absolute',
            --->left: o.left + 4,<--
                top: o.top - 20,
                display: 'none',
                color:'#000',
                fontSize:'12pt'
            }).appendTo(plot.getPlaceholder()).slideToggle();
        });
```

I am not sure if my method of adding the data from the xml into the array is incorrect or something in the options of the plot, as below:

```
$(function() {

        Init() //Load XML and load into array named data

        plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ data ], {
        grid: {
                backgroundColor: { colors: [ "#FFF", "#FFF" ] },
                borderWidth: {
                    top: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0

                }
            },
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 0, // in pixels
                    barWidth: 0.9, // in units of the x axis
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    align: "center", // "left", "right", or "center"
                    horizontal: false,
                    zero: true,
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 0,
                autoscaleMargin: 0.1
            }
        });
```

Is this maybe something to do with the mode: "Categories" line above as the x axis contain text values? Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your hypothesis is correct. If you inpect `plot.getData()[0].data`:

```
>plot.getData()[0].data
  [
    Array[2]
      0: "Team 1"
      1: 3
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array[0]
    , 
    ...
```

So, `el[0]` ends up as "Team 1" which of course isn't going to work with `pointOffset` expecting a number.

The [easiest fix to your problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/OaDCCsdqwVlzro3yFnAN?p=preview) is to use:

```
var o = plot.pointOffset({x: i, y: el[1]});  // using i instead of el[0]
```

This works because that's what the categories plugin does "under the hood", it replaces the text strings with [0,1,2,3]...

The way I would fix it though, is to *stop using the categories plugin*.  It just causes more problems then it's worth.  Use the `ticks` option and then your [existing code works fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/uoCdwYqJThpI7E81cEWW?p=preview).